# How to convert the html into pdf and view inside iframe without downloading using angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf-generation

I have a HTML template, Now when i click on PDF button, the template must be shown inside the `iframe` or `embed` and it must be in view mode inside the `iframe` or `embed,` if user needs, he can click on download icon to download the file.
I want my demo to work in this way, i am not getting how can this be solved, Can anyone help me to solve this please.

Demo: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1ebpb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

TS:

```
 captureScreen(){
  //  logic to be written here
   let doc = new jsPDF();
   let currentReportUrl =  doc.output("datauri");
   console.log(currentReportUrl,"currentReportUrl")
this.currentReportUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(    window.location.origin + currentReportUrl
  );
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you can force ANY current browser to display a PDF if the user has chosen to 'always download' it instead.

Comment: no, i want the template to view first and based on option he can download

Comment: as in this, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdzg6s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts, here when i click on pdf it is showing the contents, if i click on download icon it downloads the file